# Can I checkout a given commit from magit's log view?

Tags: magit, git

I'm exploring a git repository history using magit's log view using <kbd>l l</kbd>. Can I checkout a given commit from there without going to terminal?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

With point over the desired commit, hit <kbd>b b</kbd> for checkout, and accept the default reference, which will look something like `master~3`.